# How to convert MUI component to PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I need to convert a MUI component into a pdf.

I want to convert the following component into a pdf and open it in the browsers pdf context:

```
<Typography component="h6" variant="h5">Hello World</Typography>
```

I tried using @react-pdf/renderer

The component:

```
Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Typography component="h6" variant="h5">Hello World</Typography>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
```

I then try to open it via another function:

```
async function openPdf() {
  const pdfBlob = await pdf(<MyPdf />).toBlob();
  const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
  const pdfWindow = window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
  pdfWindow.document.title = 'My PDF Document';
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I did an project and to print with React, I used the lib 'react-to-print', was very easy.

This code is how I used:

```
const handdlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef.current,
        documentTitle: 'cedulas',
        onAfterPrint: () => alert('Print sucess'),
        pageStyle: getPageMargins
 })

return (
    <>
       <Button route="/" name="Voltar" style={{
           position: `fixed`, left: `10px`}} 
       />
       <div ref={componentRef} style={{width: '80%', height: window.innerHeight}}>
           {
              cedules.map((component, index) => {
                  console.log("here");
                  return (<div key={index} style={{margin: "50px 0"}}>
                      {component}
                   </div>)
                })
            }
       </div>
       <button onClick={handdlePrint}>Print</button>
    </>
)
```

Comment: Does this also work on firefox and safari cause I used react-to-print too but I had some issues using it on firefox and safari

Comment: what does getPageMargins do?

Comment: @elegance007 in getPageMargins I used this code

```
const getPageMargins = () => {
        let marginTop = '30px';
        let marginRight = '0px';
        let marginBottom = '30px';
        let marginLeft = '0px';
        return `@page { margin: ${marginTop} ${marginRight} ${marginBottom} ${marginLeft} !important; }`;
};
```

And in relation of firefox and safari I didn't try in this applications